# How to calculate server lantency (ping)

Tags: actionscript-3, networking, air, ping, latency

I wonder how to calculate server latency the right way.

I've created a server to client messaging system and created a packet that will calculate the server latency. This packet is setup to wait for 250ms to counter overflow.

At the moment I'm using this code:

```
    public override function handle():void
    {
        if(Client.keepAliveTimeSend != null){
            var timePassed:int = (int)(new Date().time - Client.keepAliveTimeSend.time);
            Client.ping = ((Client.ping * 3 + timePassed) / 4 ) / 4;
        }
        Client.netHandler.sendPacket(this);
        Client.keepAliveTimeSend = new Date();
    }

    public override function handleServer():void
    {
        setTimeout(Server.serverNetHandler.sendToUser, 250, clientId, this);
    }
```

When the client connects to the server, it will start sending this packet.

With this code the ping is 20 on local host, but I guess that's not right.